# Idiom-specific device orientation in Xamarin Forms on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, orientation

I want to extend an app with a tablet-friendly UI. Since the phone UI works much better in portrait orientation the existing app is locked into portrait; the tablet version does not have that restriction.

This works well on Android; the main activity decides on launch whether to allow all device orientations (on tablets) or to lock the app into portrait (on phones). The problem lies in implementing the orientation logic on iOS as well.

I know that Xamarin.Forms has a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=28388) that prevents the device orientation to be controlled from code on iOS devices. We came up with a possible workaround: All build targets are duplicated (with one instance for phones and the other for tablets) and the phone and tablet builds are uploaded to the App Store separately.

Is that really the most elegant way of achieving idiom-specific device orientation or is there a way to get around that Xamarin.Forms bug without much hassle?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the magic:

**AppDelegate.cs**

```
    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, UIWindow forWindow)
    {
        //Tablet orientation adjustment
        if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape;
        else
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
    }
```

Then create a **CustomRenderer** for `ContentPage` and override `OnElementChangedMethod`:

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Page _page = Element as Page;
            _page.Appearing += (s, ea) =>
            {
                UIInterfaceOrientation orientain = Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone ? UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait : UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft;

                NSNumber number = NSNumber.FromInt32((int)orientain);
                UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(number, new NSString("orientation"));
                UIViewController.AttemptRotationToDeviceOrientation();
            };
        }

    }
```